# Calling methods after comparing string objects from NSArray Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode4.2

I am selecting files through this code:

```
- (IBAction)selectFile:(id)sender {

    // Create the File Open Dialog class.
    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    [openDlg setPrompt:@"Select"];

    fileTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"wmv", @"3gp", @"mp4", @"avi", @"mp3", @"mma", @"wav", @"jpeg", @"png", @"jpg", @"tiff", nil];

   // NSArray *JpegfileTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"jpeg", @"png", @"jpg", @"tiff", @"mp3" nil];

    // Enable the selection of files in the dialog.
    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];

    //Enable multiple selection of files
    [openDlg setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];

    // Enable the selection of directories in the dialog.
    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];

    // Display the dialog.  If the OK button was pressed,
    // process the files.
    if ( [openDlg runModalForDirectory:nil file:nil types:fileTypes] == NSOKButton )
    {
        // Get an array containing the full filenames of all
        // files and directories selected.
        files = [[openDlg filenames] retain];

        int i; // Loop counter.
                // Loop through all the files and process them.

        for( i = 0; i < [files count]; i++ )
        {
            NSString *tempFilePath = [files objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"tempFilePath::: %@",tempFilePath);
            inputFilePath = [[files objectAtIndex:i] retain];
            NSLog(@"filename::: %@", inputFilePath);

            // Do something with the filename.
            [selectedFile setStringValue:inputFilePath];

            NSLog(@"selectedFile:::: %@", selectedFile);

        }

    }

}
```

Then after selection I have used this code to process the selected file.

```
- (IBAction)setMessage:(id)sender {

    [fileGenProgress startAnimation:self];

    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Started"];
    [lblMessage setStringValue:message];
    [message release];

    [self startProcessingVideoFile];
    [self startProcessingAudioFile];
    [self startProcessingJpg];

}
```

The issue I am facing is that, I am not getting that how would I compare the different strings like if the selected file was 3gp/mp4 or jpg or mp3. As if user has selected some video file then the method `[self startProcessingVideoFile];` will run and if he has selected some JPG or PNG etc file then `[self startProcessingAudioFile];` method will run.
As selected will be having a path not only the extension of the file. So in this scenario how can I force the `- (IBAction)setMessage:(id)sender` method to run the appropriate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get string's extension (format) like this:

```
NSString *extension = [stringPath pathExtension];
```

And for comparing now it's very easy when You know what extension Your file is. **For example:**

```
NSLog(extension);

if ([extension isEqualToString:@"3gp"] || [ext isEqualToString:@"mp4"]) {

    [self startProcessingVideoFile];
}
```

and etc.

**Update:**

Your `IBAction:SetMessage` should look like this:

```
- (IBAction)setMessage:(id)sender {

    [fileGenProgress startAnimation:self];

    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Started"];
    [lblMessage setStringValue:message];
    [message release];


    NSString *extension = [inputFilePath pathExtension];

    NSLog(extension);

    if ([extension isEqualToString:@"3gp"] || [ext isEqualToString:@"mp4"]) {

        [self startProcessingVideoFile];
    }

    // And etc for others formats.
    //[self startProcessingAudioFile];
    //[self startProcessingJpg];
```

}

Comment: Thanx Justin Boo, but NSString *extension = [string pathExtension]; is not being accepted, where to use it ?

Comment: @iError string is Your path to file. In Your code I see "inputFilePath". Look at update.